# is there a way to see if a client socket on my serverside is dead?

Tags: c, server-side, client-side

when a client connects to my server side, after they connect if they switch to a VPN or something the server side still says the socket is alive and still tries to read from it i tried using another thread to check all my sockets constantly with read and close it if it returns -1 but it still doesn't do anything

Answer (score 0):

It very depends on what type of protocol you use, but generalized question is : yes and no. You have to learn network protocol stack to know what you csn do in you situations, details of which you did not disclose.

Usual way to solve this problem is establish some policy or two way cpmmunocation. E.g. there was np data or "i'm alive" message send from client X for duration of time Y, we close connection. Or, send a regular "ping" message to client C and expect a response before period Y expires.

Answer (score 0):

If we're talking TCP, and if the client's connection is properly closed, a message is sent to the server, so the server will know the connection is closed, so read/recv will return 0 bytes indicating EOF.

But you're asking about the times when the client becomes unable to communicate with the server. Detecting an absence of messages is necessarily done using a timeout.

1. You can have the server "ping" the client (send a message to which the client must respond) periodically.
2. You can have the client send a message periodically (a "heartbeat") when idle.

Either way, no message (of any kind) for X seconds indicates a broken connection.

Answer (score 0):

If you enable the `SO_KEEPALIVE` socket option on each new TCP connection, the OS will automatically ping the remote side periodically to see if it still responds, and close the connection if it doesn't. The default timeout is several hours, but many OSes allow you to configure a lower timeout on a per-socket basis. Unfortunately, each one is different in how to do this. Linux, for example, uses the `TCP_KEEPIDLE` socket option. NetBSD (And probably other BSDs) uses `TCP_KEEPALIVE`. And so on.